# Integers recorded fine in SQlite, but recorded as 0 in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, flask, integer

When saving from `Flask` script to `SQLite` via `Flask SQLAlchemy`, my integers save normally. When saving to `Mysql`, my integers save as 0.

I have a save function in `Flask` - when my `dotenv` variable points flask to `SQLite`, this saves the data quite fine. When my `dotenv` points `Flask` to `Mysql`, I get the name of the signal `(string)`, the id, but all my prices `(int)` are recorded as zero. What's strange is that my interpreter prints to the console all the data before it saves and it seems fine - its listed below.

I also get a signal (as in Flask db save signal) to print out the 'changes', which also show the numbers as expected, and yet my database doesn't record the data properly.

**Save function**

```
def save(signal, zig_user):
    signal_to_save = Signal(**signal)
    print(f"Signal to save is {signal_to_save}")
    print(f"signal  {signal}")
    print(f"signal  takeProfitPrice1: {signal_to_save.takeProfitPrice1}")
    zig_user.signals.append(signal_to_save)
    db.session.commit()
```

**console output both for SQlite and MySQL**

```
Signal to save is <Signal ETHBTC, price: 0.00001200 , targets: 0.000011400.000011900.00001300 from UserID: None>
signal  {'type': 'buy', 'exchange': 'binance', 'market': 'ETHBTC', 'limitPrice': '0.00001400', 'price': '0.00001200', 'positionSizePercentage': '2', 'stopLossPrice': '0.00001000', 'takeProfitPrice1': '0.00001140', 'takeProfitPrice2': '0.00001190', 'takeProfitPrice3
': '0.00001300', 'key': 'fb470345fdb1ef832f0a2951f270be82'}
signal  takeProfitPrice 10.00001140
```

**flask save signal:**

```
[2019-09-25 11:23:49,457] INFO in __init__: Added (2, 'ETHBTC', '0.00001140', '0.00001190', '0.00001300')
```

And yet when I look in the database this is what I get:

SQLite:
signal.takeProfitPrice1
0.00001140

MYSQL
signal.takeProfitPrice1
0

**I have one error:**

```
site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:170: Warning: (3719, "'utf8' is currently an alias for the character set UTF8MB3, but will be an alias for UTF8MB4 in a future release. Please consider using UTF8MB4 in order to be unambiguou
s.")
```

**Update**

This is what my sql table looks like:

Column: takeProfitPrice1
Definition:
takeProfitPrice1 int(11)

Comment: What is your schema?

Comment: Added scheme info to my question.

Comment: Other than that - my schema says utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

Comment: All of my schema was made by flask db init - i just setup a standard mysql schema. Flask did the rest from my models, strings and ID saves fine.

Comment: `0.00001140` is not an integer... bet MySQL is truncating that floating point number to an integer (0).

Comment: That's the answer shawn if you want to post it I'll accept it and you'll get magic karma points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to store a floating point number in an integer column.

Sqlite uses dynamic typing, and the column type is just a hint as to the preferred way to store and compare values (See https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html for details; understanding the concept of *affinity* described there is essential for working with sqlite). It'll happily insert values of other types when asked. MySQL (And pretty much every other database) doesn't behave the same way and converts that very small, close to 0 number to 0. You need to change your table schema to reflect the type of data you're actually storing for it to work with MySQL.